# Angular 2+ http service is being called, but request is not going out

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to be able to instantiate a model class, but also give it access to services.

For example, say I have these endpoints:

```
/book/:id
/book/:id/author
```

I want to have a `BooksService` service to fetch a list a `Book` instance.   I'd like the book instances to be instantiated with `new`, given a definition JSON through the constructor, while still being able to use Angular dependencies.

Example of what I want to do:

```
BooksService.getBook(1)       // makes call to /book/1
    .subscribe((book) => {
        book.getAuthor()  // makes call to /book/1/author
        ...
    });
```

To accomplish this, I tried to use a factory to `new` an instance of a book model.  I then pass in a reference to the Http injected dependency that the factory injects.

Here's what I have:

**BooksService**

```
@Injectable()
export class BookService {
    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private bookModelFactory: BookModelFactory
    ) {}

    getBook(): Observable<BookModel> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/book/1')
            .map((res) => {
                return this.bookModelFactory.make(res.json().data);
            });
    }
}
```

**BookModel, BookModelFactory**

```
@Injectable()
export class BookModelFactory {
    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    make(def: object): BookModel {
        var book = new BookModel(def);
        book.http = this.http;
        return book;
    }
}

export class BookModel {
    def: any;
    http: Http;

    constructor (def: object) {
        this.def = def;
    }

    getAuthor() {
        console.log('http', this.http);
        this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/book/1/author');
    }
}
```

When I try to use this code, I see the console log for the http object in `book.getAuthor()`.  It exists, and I can see the `get` method on it.  But it never makes the API request. Nothing in the network tab has anything about a call to `/book/1/author`.  There are no errors.  Simply put, nothing happens.

Why isn't the request being made when `this.http.get('...')` is being called in `getAuthors()`?

Thanks in advance.

Using Angular 4.

*(Imports statements are removed for brevity)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2) If this is a good strategy... why isn't the request being made when this.http.get('...') is being called in getAuthors()?

Because no-one ever subscribed to the results of this call:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/book/1/author').subscribe(res => {
    // do something with the results here
});
```

In angular if you do not subscribe to the results of the HTTP call, then this call will never be made.

Or maybe you want your `getAuthor` method to return an `Observable<Author>` so that it is the caller of this method that can subscribe to the results:

```
getAuthor(): Observable<Author> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/book/1/author').map(res => {
        return res.json().data;
    });
}
```

So that you can subscribe to it later:

```
BooksService.getBook(1)       // makes call to /book/1
    .subscribe(book => {
        book.getAuthor() // makes call to /book/1/author
            .subscribe(author => {
                // do something with the book author here
            });
        ...
    });
```

So remember, if you do not subscribe, the AJAX call will not be made.

Comment: Ahhh, interesting, I just figured it would fire off the GET request immediately, then register the the .map and .subscribe to process whatever came back.  Works now, thank you!